# How to compare 2 list and print based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to compare two different list and print it out based on index.

This is my code so far:

```
valList = [['-60.93'], ['6.0'], ['10.0'], ['24.0'], ['26.57'], ['60.0']]
expList = [['((-500+(4*3.14))/(2**3))'], ['((1+2)+3)', '(2+(2+2))'], ['((1+2)+(3+4))', '((1+2)+(3+(3+1)))', '(((((((((1+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)'], ['(((1+2)+3)*4)'], ['((11.07+25.5)-10)'], ['(10+(20+30))', '((10+(10+(10+10)))+(10+10))']]
print(valList)
print(expList)
print()

for x in valList:
    for l in expList:
        print(f'{l}')
    print(f'*** Expressions with value = {x}')
```

The output that i want is something like this:
[image: Link to image output here]

But as of now, the output is not i want as it just prints out all the items of expList for each valList item. I am very new to programming so help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `zip` to iterate both lists in parallel, then print the data as needed

```
for vals, exps in zip(valList, expList):
    result = vals[0]
    print(f'*** Expressions with value = {result}')
    for e in exps:
        print(f'{e} ==> {result}')
    print()
```

---

As the `valList` contains only 1-element lists, I'd suggest to change it to a list of string directly

```
valList = ['-60.93', '6.0', '10.0', '24.0', '26.57', '60.0']
expList = [...]
for val, exps in zip(valList, expList):
    print(f'*** Expressions with value = {val}')
    for e in exps:
        print(f'{e} ==> {val}')
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it way better now :)